# User limits in Portal for ArcGIS

Tags: license, arcgis-portal

In Portal for ArcGIS, I have 100 user limit.

I know that Portal can take users information from LDAP or any 3rd provide software which stores users information.

If I have 101 users in LDAP, and portal user limit is 100, will Portal take more users than 100?

Comment: I think this is best answered by ESRI's support. Have you asked them?

Comment: No I haven't yet. The thing is will Portal support more than 100 users if I bind LDAP users with Portal.

Answer (score 11):

100 users are provided by the license. If you want to add more users you will have to buy a new license that will allow you to make more users in the portal. The LDAP won't allow you to have more users than 100, because it has no dependency with LDAP users.

Answer (score 2):

This is from the [ESRI Support Website](http://server.arcgis.com/en/portal/latest/administer/linux/enforcement-of-named-user-licensing.htm):

> If the maximum number of registered members per membership level exceeds your license entitlement, you are no longer in compliance with the license. [...] If you are not in compliance with your licensing, the following
>   occurs:
>
> - Accessing the portal website with an account that has administrative    privileges displays the membership level that has
>     been exceeded with    red text indicating the number of registered
>     members per membership    level. This indication is displayed each
>     time the portal website is    accessed by an administrator.
> - Accessing the portal website, the    ArcGIS Portal Directory, and the portal through ArcGIS Desktop with a    non-administrative account
>     displays a sign-in error message stating    the member cannot sign in
>     to the portal because of a software    authorization error. The member
>     is directed to contact the portal    administrator for assistance. The
>     member cannot access the portal    until the software authorization
>     error is resolved.
> - New member    accounts cannot be created through the portal website or the ArcGIS    Portal Directory. If a user attempts to create a
>     member account, an    error message displays stating the account could
>     not be created    because of a software authorization error. The user
>     is directed to    contact the portal administrator for assistance.